# How to write a VBA code me which displays 10 random numbers between 1 to 50 without a repeat of the numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, algorithm

How do I write a VBA code me which displays 10 random numbers between 1 to 50 without a repeat of the numbers?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

In **B1** through **B50** enter:

```
 =RAND()
```

In **A1** enter:

```
=MATCH(LARGE(B:B,ROW()),B:B,0)
```

and copy down through **A10**:

[image]

Just write a short macro to insert the formulas.  If you don't want to use the worksheet approach then:

```
Sub WillNotRepeat()
   Dim ndex(1 To 50)
   For I = 1 To 50
      ndex(I) = I
   Next I

   Call Shuffle(ndex)

   For I = 1 To 10
      msg = msg & ndex(I) & vbCrLf
   Next I
   MsgBox msg
End Sub

Public Sub Shuffle(InOut() As Variant)
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    Dim tempF As Double, Temp As Variant

    Hi = UBound(InOut)
    Low = LBound(InOut)
    ReDim Helper(Low To Hi) As Double
    Randomize

    For I = Low To Hi
        Helper(I) = Rnd
    Next I


    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If Helper(I) > Helper(I + J) Then
            tempF = Helper(I)
            Helper(I) = Helper(I + J)
            Helper(I + J) = tempF
            Temp = InOut(I)
            InOut(I) = InOut(I + J)
            InOut(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA:

```
Public Sub customRandom()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    wks.Rows.Clear
    totalNumbers = 10
    minValue = 1
    maxValue = 50
    firstRow = 1
    firstColumn = 1
    Randomize
    Dim results() As Integer
    ReDim results(totalNumbers)
    For i = 1 To totalNumbers
        randoming = True
        While randoming
            notfound = True
            a = Int(Rnd() * maxValue) + minValue
            For j = 1 To totalNumbers
                If a = results(j) Then
                    notfound = False
                    j = totalNumbers
                End If
            Next j
            If notfound = True Then
                results(i) = a
                randoming = False
                wks.Cells(firstRow, firstColumn) = a
                firstRow = firstRow + 1
            End If
        Wend
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It will fill cells *A1* to *A10*, but it can be changed easily with the variables `firstRow`and `firstColumn`.